# Six months have passed since paper has been accepted and it was not yet published - has the editor changed his mind?

Tags: publications

About 10 months ago, I submitted one little article to a journal and six months ago I received the acceptance. I uploaded the latex file and since then I didn't hear anything about it being published.

Today it appeared a new issue of the journal so I must wait at least another 3 months.

This will be my first published article and I started to become a little nervous about it.

Can you tell me if something happened, like editor's changing his mind or delaying because they consider it less valuable than other submissions?

Should I contact my editor about this?

Comment: @henning: That only aspect that Q&A answers is whether the editor may have unaccepted the paper. I would not consider it a duplicate.

Comment: Did you check whether the journal usually publishes other articles online before they are published in print? What about other articles that were accepted around the same times as yours? Are they already published?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is very unlikely that the article has been "unaccepted", and as far as I know, most journals publish articles basically in order (modulo some special issues and things like that).

However most journals have backlogs, and can take a long time from submission of the final copy to getting the article to print.  I don't know how common that is in your field, but for math, in 2015, the AMS [published some data](http://www.ams.org/notices/201510/rnoti-p1266.pdf) on how long it takes math journals to publish an article; a quick glance shows that gaps of much longer than six months between acceptance and publication are common.

Answer (score 0):

Many journals can take several months between when they tell authors the paper is accepted, and when the article appears in the print copy of the journal.  (This is totally anecdotal, but in my experience, the time gap between acceptance and printing tends to be larger for journals that have shorter turnaround times for review and acceptance.)

Suggest first pulsing your coauthors, peers, and/or colleagues on what their experience has been with this particular journal.  If they suggest that this is out-of-normal for this journal, you might try contacting the editor who sent you the acceptance notification.

Comment: In fact, some journals even print on the first page of each article: submission date and acceptance date.